# javascript check and replace two strings

Tags: javascript, string, compare, indexof

I have two strings `str1` and `str2`. Check both of them and see if any one string is empty.

If yes, then replace that str with another one.

```
if(indexOf(str1) < -1 || indexOf(str2) < -1){
   str1 = str2;
 }
```

will this work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, that won't work for numerous reasons. This will though:

```
if(!str1)
    str1 = str2;
else if(!str2)
    str2 = str1;
```